# Is there a tool to determine whether a program is "correctly synchronized" as defined in JLS?

Tags: java, concurrency, jls, java-memory-model

The Java Language Specification 7 (JLS7-17.4.5) defines a "correctly synchronized" program like this: "A program is correctly synchronized if and only if all sequentially consistent executions are free of data races".

JLS7-17.4.5 also states that:

> Without correct synchronization, very strange, confusing and counterintuitive behaviors are possible.

So, from a programmer's point of view, it would be very useful to have a tool to determine whether a program is "correctly synchronized" according the the above definition.

Is there such a tool? I could not find anything by Googling on it. If there is no such tool, would it be possible to make one?

Comment: Google for "Java static data race detection".

Answer (score 4):

[FindBugs](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/) can find some concurrency bugs (search for "Multithreaded correctness" on [the list of detected bugs](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/bugDescriptions.html)) and there probably are other similar tools, but in the end some bugs can only be avoided with meticulous code design and review.

You can also test your classes for concurrency issues, but it is a game of statistics and some bugs might never show up depending on OS/CPU architecture etc.

I have heard about the [Java concurrency torture](https://github.com/shipilev/java-concurrency-torture) tool, but never used it. It has been mentioned several times on the official [JSR 166 Concurrency Interest list](http://cs.oswego.edu/pipermail/concurrency-interest/2012-October/010178.html).

Comment: I am aware of some tools that can be used to test whether a program is correctly synchronized in a general sense. However, what I am interested in is a tool that can determine whether a program is correctly synchronized according to the _exact definition_ of a "correctly synchronized" program in JLS7-17.4.5.

Comment: @FransLundberg Note that "correctly synchronized" is a subset of "multithreaded correctness". For example if 2 statements are individually correctly synchronized, you might still have a general correctness issue if the program requires them to also be atomic.

Comment: @FransLundberg cf 17.4.3 *If a program has no data races, then all executions of the program will appear to be sequentially consistent. Sequential consistency and/or freedom from data races still allows errors arising from groups of operations that need to be perceived atomically and are not.* So your question could be rephrased to statically finding data races as suggested by Marko in another comment.

Comment: @FransLundberg Interesting discussion here: https://communities.coverity.com/thread/2103

Comment: thanks for the input and the link. I agree with your comments: "correctly synchronized" is a subset of "multithreaded correctness". And  the question could be rephrased as you/Marko state.