# How to test multi-thread/concurrency method correctly in java?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

Is there a tool like `JUnit`?

Any suggestion abount writing test for multi-thread/concurrency methods?

Comment: In general it's hard... you should provide an example.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14400367/829571

Comment: @home there maybe many kinds of code? maybe my question is: are there any principle for writing test?

Comment: Also worth mentioning that JCiP (Java Concurrency in Practice) has a whole chapter about testing concurrent applications.

Answer (score 0):

You can devise basic multi-threading tests, typically using things like CountDownLatch to make different threads do different things at specific times.  However, the nature of multi-threading is that when it's broken, there are a myriad of subtle ways that it can be messed up, and testing typically hits *none* of those scenarios.

So, in practice, while you *can* write multi-threaded unit tests, the fact that they didn't fail generally proves nothing.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar requirement and was exploring a lot. Came across Thread-Weaver framework from Google @ https://code.google.com/p/thread-weaver/wiki/UsersGuide .Looks like a pretty decent framework. Although, I do not see many blogs/users of this framework. My next stack overflow question will be the same :-)